# Bulding a vector on python from mutiple text files

Tags: python, vector

I'm trying to build a python script to calculate averages. To do so, I need to build a vector with 10 columns. Each input comes from a different text file with many text lines, and I need the number from a specific line that looks like this:

```
BAR: dG =   -23.98 kcal/mol
```

Each file has a different number for this line. How can I get only the number after the string `"BAR: dG =   "` from these text files and use as an input for a vector like this:

```
yi = ["number from file 1", "number from file 2" , ... , "number from file 10"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using regular expressions. The following code does the trick in case your filenames are in a list already.

```
import re
values = []
files_list = ['f1.txt','f2.txt','f3.txt','f4.txt','f5.txt','f6.txt','f7.txt','f8.txt','f9.txt','f10.txt']
for f in files_list:
    fp = open(f,'r')
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # This line tries to match your pattern with the current line
        matches = re.match(r'BAR: dG =\s+(\-\d+\.\d+)\skcal/mol',line)
        if(matches): # If there is a match, then do something with the value
            value = matches.group(1)
            print(value)
            values.append(float(value))
average = sum(values)/10
print(average)
```

Comment: The output is empty

Comment: I have tested this code by placing your example ```BAR: dG =   -23.98 kcal/mol``` in a random text file of mine, and it worked.  Do you always have that minus sign before the number? If the numbers can be positive, then the regex must be corrected

Comment: It worked. The line actually starts with double spacing and then the string BAR ...
Thank you! Now I need to learn the loop part

Comment: Nice. In case you need it to work with positive numbers also, just add an asterisk after the minus sign ```re.match(r'BAR: dG =\s+(\-*\d+\.\d+)\skcal/mol',line)```

Comment: Nice! Will need this for the other half of my simulations. Thank again! 
Any useful link to learn about loop in python?

Comment: I edited the answer to cover the for-loop part. If you need to run this for different sets of files, take a look at the ```glob``` package and ```sys.argv``` for passing filenames as parameters

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thank you very much!